# Can Git push differences only?

Tags: git, version-control

Consider this (typical) scenario: in the same team backend developers are working on optimizing DB queries, while front end developers are fixing layout bugs. In SVN it is possible to commit changes even if you don't have the latest revision checked out on your development machine. This means that front end developers can commit their layout fixes while back end developers are committing their fixes in parallel. Front end developers don't have to pull the back end fixes in order to commit, thus they can avoid rebuilding and/or redeploying their DB every time they want to commit.

Is it possible in Git to push changes even if your local HEAD is outdated?

Comment: That scenario is what branches/merges are dessigned for.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to work this way, then maybe you can reorganize your project into submodules, so that your frontend and backend teams can work together more independently.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not. But this is not a big problem because you can just do

```
git pull
```

and in git 1.7.0 or later at least, it will merge in changes to all files, including files you were not working on, which should merge without any problems of course.

Regarding recompiling... yes I see what you mean. But arguably it is a good idea to rebuild/test before committing anyway, to ensure that the tree always builds, passes tests etc.

Comment: OP's motivation seems to be allowing front end guys to "avoid rebuilding and/or redeploying their DB every time".